# migration of clients, addresses and prestashop 1.7 orders

Tags: prestashop-1.7

I copied the complete folder of my prestashop 1.7.3.0 on a new folder on my server with new database, install a new theme and maj prestashop in 1.7.7.0

The concern is that now that I have finished in the meantime I have had orders and customers.

I imported the products in excel redone the variations by hand.

How can I subsequently export customers and orders?

In excel import of my last clients it tells me that the password is required for the import?

What would be the best method even going on phpmyadmin to import the customers, addresses and orders that I miss on the new store?

Thanks for your feedback.

Answer (score 0):

To align customers and addresses you can use Prestashop's built-in CSV import feature.

Regarding orders there is no standard way to do it,
you have to perform queries on the new database synchronizing the missing data of the old one, taking care to check the various tables of the site because there are several entities involved (and structure might change between PS versions too).

Also keep in mind that there may be third party modules on the old site that save data and therefore must be synchronized.

Other options: you'll put "catalog mode" on the live store for a few days until you've finished the work on the new one or use a paid data migration module that can perform incremental migrations.

Answer (score 0):

This is always a headache, but if there isn't any changes on the order/customer related databases it should be pretty easy.

1 Check if the database structure is the same (no new columns)

1.1 If there are new columns os some have changed a small script will work best for you. (check if the register exist, if not create it, update the columns from the old to the new...)  << That's the complicated case.

1.2 If both databases have the same columns and specs, just perform a copy from the old to the new (copy or a export/import through the phpmyadmin).

You will have to perform this for every database you want to update (order, order_detail, customers...) but it should be enough.

---

If none of the above works for you and the upgrade process did not create any error, there is a third method, it may take a bit long but you will be able to update the data. Create a new subdomain/test site, clone the 1.7.3.0 there and upgrade it. Now put the original one into maintenance mode while you perform the page migration. With the new clone selected on phpmyadmin export the order related databases and import them to the other site where you did upgrade the shop. Since this is also an updated version all databases should have the same structure so copying the data should be relativelly easy.

Once copied and working swap the test site for the main one, remove the maintenance mode and you should have everything updated and running. Do this at a low visitors hour to minimize the impact on the sales.